# How to avoid strained back muscles on lateral raise machine?

Tags: deltoids

Whenever I use the lateral raise machine I get a really great connection with my side delts, but I also tend to activate the muscles on either side of the spine a little too much. The day after using the machine I almost always seem to get these really painful muscle knots right by the spine on the mid/upper back (not sure what the muscles in question are called).

Does anyone have an idea why this is and what might be some adjustments to avoid tensing the back too much?